# Infix to Postfix - Deleting Parenthesis

Tags: c++, stack

Having trouble getting the parenthesis to pop from the string.
I enter an infix expression such as `(A+B)*C` and would like to get `AB+C*`.
Instead, I get `(AB)+C*`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 string Postfx::convertToPostfix(Postfx C,string in)
    {
    stack<char> S;
    string postfx = "";



    for (int i = 0; i<in.length();i++)
    {
        if (in[i] == ' ' || in[i] == ',') continue;

        else if ((in[i]) == '+' || in[i] == '-' || in[i] == '/' || in[i] == '*')
        {
            while (!S.empty() && S.top() != '(' && C.precedence(S.top(), in[i]))
            {
                postfx += S.top();
                S.pop();
            }
            S.push(in[i]);
        }

        else if ((in[i]) != '+' || in[i] != '-' || in[i] != '/' || in[i] != '*')
        {
            postfx += in[i];
        }

        else if (in[i] == '(')
        {
            S.push(in[i]);
        }
        else if (in[i] == ')')
        {
            while (!S.empty() && S.top() != '(')
            {
                postfx += S.top();
                S.pop();
            }
            S.pop();
        }
    }

    while (!S.empty()) {
        postfx += S.top();
        S.pop();
    }

    return postfx;
}
```

Comment: The inverse of `A or B or C` is *not* `not A or not B or not C`. See [De Morgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Answer (score 1):

I think that your

```
else if ((in[i]) != '+' || in[i] != '-' || in[i] != '/' || in[i] != '*')
```

line catches brackets as well, so

```
else if (in[i] == '(')
```

and below never gets executed.

I think you should move

```
else if ((in[i]) != '+' || in[i] != '-' || in[i] != '/' || in[i] != '*')
```

to be the last option in the chained if.

Moreover, this `if` catches absolutely *any* symbol (because any symbol is either not equal to `'+'`, or not equal to `'-'`). You need to replace `||` by `&&`; but if you will anyway have this `if` the last in chained if, you need no condition there at all, something like:

```
if ((in[i] == ' ')|| ...
else if ((in[i] == '+')|| ...
else if (in[i] == '(') ...
else if (in[i] == ')') ...
else postfx += in[i]; // no condition here
```

P.S. Also if you wrap the initial expression in brackets:

```
in = "(" + in + ")"
```

before the loop, you will not need the final `while (!S.empty())` loop.

Comment: Yes, for that first block of code, there's not *any* character for which, say, `!='-'` *and* `!='/'` will both be false.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes, also noticed this and updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't append the parentheses to the output. They're only in the stack to guide your actions. I don't know where you got this code but you need to take a good look at the [Dijkstra Shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). Your version doesn't match it at several points, and some of it doesn't even make sense:

```
if (in[i] != '+' || in[i] != '-' || in[i] != '/' || in[i] != '*')
```